# ES6 Class property undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

```
class Person{
constuctor(name){
    this.name = name;
}

speak(){
    alert('My name is ' + this.name);
}

}

var james = new Person('james');

james.speak();
```

I'm trying learn ES6 classes for some node stuff.
Every example I find says this should work, but name is always undefined.
I must be missing something really simple.

I have a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gxjhmgyu/

Comment: You have a typo - `constuctor` -> `constructor`

Comment: ahhhh! sorry, sometimes it's the things right in front you you.

Comment: If you have a decent IDE, it should change the colour of the text for reserved words such as `constructor`. Try to notice when it's the wrong colour :-)

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to open your JavaScript Console (F12 on chrome) and type / paste this stuff RIGHT in - then you can even `console.log` or `console.table` which is much more convenient than `alert`

Comment: @DavidKnipe I'm using sublime 3, and I just downloaded a syntax package specifically for ES6. It doesn't catch it, constructor has the same color as any other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a typo in your code. See the fixed link below, its the same as your code.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    speak() {
            alert('My name is ' + this.name);
    }
}

var james = new Person('James');
james.speak();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gxjhmgyu/1/

Comment: Thanks. I had very similar problem.